# what is userDn and base in LDAP terminology

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I want to authenticate a user in `LDAP` using *spring* in java. I found that for configuration of `LDAP` with *spring*, I need *urls*, *userDn*, *password* & base values like shown below:

```
urls=ldap://127.0.0.1:389
userDn=cn=Directory Manager
password=abcd
base=dc=example,dc=com
```

My question is, what is exactly this *userDn* and *base*? What does these signifies? And which *userDn* value we need to specify in this configuration??

Comment: Here you go, googled LDAP DN: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apa/dn-rdn.html

Answer (score 5):

The `base object` is the point in the directory information tree (DIT) at which the search should begin constructing candidates for entries to return in the search result. The `scope` of the search search determine the depth of the tree as follows:

- *subtree* scope: the base object and al entries subordinate to the base object
- *one*: all objects immediately subordinate to the base object, but not including the base object.
- *base*: just the base object. base level search should always be used when the distinguished name is known.

The `userDn` in this case appears to be a distinguished name of a user that will authenticate to the directory using a BIND request.

#### see also

- [LDAP Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)